# Choice without pressing enter?

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to make a choice dialogue where the user only presses the number without the need of pressing enter?

```
$options = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]] @("&All", "&Client", "&Server")
$opt = $host.UI.PromptForChoice("Your Choice", "Files", $Options, 0)
```

In this example the user has to press <kbd>A</kbd>,<kbd>Enter</kbd>. I want that the user only has to press <kbd>A</kbd>.

Comment: Why does it matter whether the user must press Enter or not?

Comment: @bill: it matters to me. Pressing enter can be time expansive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps surprisingly, you can use [`choice`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732504.aspx):

```
choice /c acs /m 'Your Choice'
switch ($LASTEXITCODE) {
  1 { 'You chose "All".' }
  2 { 'You chose "Client".' }
  3 { 'You chose "Server".' }
}
```

Comment: @etalon11 it's neither - it's an external executable that ships with Windows. Does it matter?

Comment: So I have to give it a try. Thanks

Comment: Be aware that `choice` will only work in the standard PowerShell console (not ISE, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `[system.console]::Readkey()`

Comment: And how can I combine this with "PromptForChoice"? Can you modify my example? Thanks.

Comment: In ISE it works fine :)

When you want to build kind of menu, you can have a look at the switch Statement to determine the pressed key:
$a = [System.Console]::ReadKey() 
        switch ( $a.key)
        {
            a,A { reaction_on_a }
            c, C { do_something_else }
        }